# Creating a custom "event listener" with es6 modules

Tags: javascript

We are working on creating custom event listener on Javascript. Tried out a few examples but couldn't get custom event listener to be called. Code example:

**events.js**

```
function init() {
    return new Promise(() => {
        console.log('successfully initialized!');
    });
}

// this symbolizes some event occurring randomly. in reality, this will eventually be
// something like a webhook getting hit, or a websocket, etc. for now we just use
// setTimeout to simulate this event coming in at some time after init has been called
setTimeout(on, 15000);

// on is called anytime any event occurs. in this example, we hardcode that event1 occurred
function on() {
    console.log('event1 occurred in events.js');
    return 'event1';
}​

const events = {
    init,
    on,
};

export default events;
```

**index.js**

```
events.init(() => {
        // here we should see console log about successful initialization
    }).then(() => {
        // here, we want to "listen" for event1 to occur
        events.on('event1', () => {
            console.log('we were notified about event1 happening!');
        });
    });
```

In this example we see following being displayed in browser console

```
successfully initialized!
```

And then few seconds later:

```
event1 occurred in events.js
```

As shown in example callback code for "event1" from index.js is never called, instead "on" function from events.js is called.
What we need is a custom event listener to work so we can call "event1" from index.js console.log should display

```
we were notified about event1 happening!
```

Thank you for reviewing the question and helping with solution.

Comment: I don't see what this question has to do with ES6 modules. The code doesn't work either if it was in a single file.

Comment: Uh, your `on` declaration (a function without parameters) doesn't match your `on(…)` call (with two arguments, one of them a callback) at all.

Comment: You've confused the usage of `emit` and `on` methods on a Node-style event emitter... And your `init` promise never resolves... This code has *more than one* issues.

Comment: @Bergi I want events.js to be an ES6 module that's why added es6 module in the title this needs to work modular and not in single file

Comment: @FZs yes this is an example code in actual code promise resolve and reject will be added. Right now main concern is making custom event listener working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say that there are few problems here.

**1. Unresolved promise**

First of all, you're not resolving the promise, this means that the `then` callback never gets called.

So, at first you should update the `init` method as the following:

```js
function init() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log('successfully initialized!');

    // when you're done with your stuff, tell outside
    resolve()
  });
}
```

**2. Tracking callbacks**

Than, you're not keeping track of the different callback for the different type of events. The on method should than save the tuple event-callback in an appropriate map as the following:

```js
const handlers = {}
function on(event, callback) {
  handlers[event] = callback;
}
```

**3. Event emission**

The last thing that I think you are missing is the concept of "emission" of an event. When something *in particular* happen, you should emit a proper event. Than, if it has been registered a callback, you're going to call it.

So, you need to add a third `emit` method to your `events` api as the following:

```js
function emit(event) {
  const callback = handlers[event];

  // if we registered a callback before, and it is a function,
  // let's call it  
  if ( callback && typeof callback === 'function' )
    callback()
}
```

Your final export becomes:

```js
const events = {
  init,
  on,
  emit
};
```

With this new method, you can simulate your call emitting the event `event1` as the one you're registering:

```js
setTimeout(() => emit('event1'), 5000);
```

It seems to work like a charm :)

### EDIT

I'm not sure if this might be the exact use case asked by @Shehzad Nizamani, but we can do `emit` triggers all registered callbacks if no particular events are given, something like:

```js
setTimeout(emit, 5000)

function emit(event) {
  if ( event ) {
    const callback = handlers[event];

    // if we registered a callback before, and it is a function,
    // let's call it  
    if ( callback && typeof callback === 'function' )
      callback()

  // if no event is given, we trigger all the callbacks
  } else {

    const callbacks = Object.values(handlers)
    callbacks.forEach(callback => {
      if ( typeof callback === 'function' )
        callback()
    })
  }
}
```

```js
function init() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log('successfully initialized!');

    // when you're done with your stuff, tell outside
    resolve()
  });
}

// emit a specific event to trigger the relative callback
setTimeout(() => emit('event1'), 10000);
setTimeout(emit, 5000);

// we need to keep track of a map
// between event types and their callback
const handlers = {}
function on(event, callback) {
  handlers[event] = callback;
}

// we need a new api that triggers registered callbacks
function emit(event) {
  if ( event ) {
    const callback = handlers[event];

    // if we registered a callback before, and it is a function,
    // let's call it  
    if ( callback && typeof callback === 'function' )
      callback()

  // if no event is given, we trigger all the callbacks
  } else {

    const callbacks = Object.values(handlers)
    callbacks.forEach(callback => {
      if ( typeof callback === 'function' )
        callback()
    })
  }
}

const events = {
  init,
  on,
  emit
};

events.init(
  () => {
    // here we should see console log
    //about successful initialization
  }
).then(
  () => {
    
    // here, we want to "listen" for event1 to occur
    events.on('event1', () => {
      console.log('we were notified about event1 happening!');
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer I appreciate you input I tried this out code works but can this code work without this line:
setTimeout(() => emit('event1'), 5000);

Comment: I tried it out appears that event isn't being called without emit('event1'); call could you please help me with this also

Comment: Well, as en event system, at certain point in your program you'll need to emit an event. In that moment you should call the emit method. Maybe I am missing the point of having an event handling system without the chance of emitting an event. Do you need a method that triggers al the callbacks maybe?

Comment: @ShehzadNizamani I updated my answer to resemble what it seems to be your use case.

Comment: So you mean without emitting an event there is no way to run "event1" callback? Because in our use case we need events to be called without emitting them

Comment: There is a way, I updated my answer to reach that goal. It's just that... it doesn't make much sense though, at least in the "event listener" pattern. Did you check the updated snippet?

Comment: Yes I am trying it out, what I want it that there is no call to emit and events are called